# RFC3339 grok pattern for logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Hi i need use millisecond into syslog file, i have commented out the `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` template fron rsyslog.conf and now i have timestamp in RFC3339 format, i need parse this timestamp but I do not know what pattern to use.

New format is:

`2017-10-25T17:30:31.790589+02:00`

does a pattern exist for the match? I search at https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok patterns but not have find anything

Comment: This format matches the regular ISO8601 timestamp pattern, from [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns#L68).

Comment: Yes, thanks, works fine! You can answer